# How/where does Flask-Caching store data?

Tags: flask, flask-caching

I just wonder how and where the response is stored when using Flask-Caching.

For example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_caching import Cache
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

def make_cache_key(*args, **kwargs):
    return request.url

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cache.cached(timeout=50, key_prefix=make_cache_key)
def foo():
    time = str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + str(request.url)
    return time, 200

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

In your example, it'll be stored in-memory of the Python interpreter.

---

Your setup is in-memory, so it won't scale between multiple servers. However, you have the option to specify a different cache backend (memcached or Redis, for example, or even your own custom one by extending the base cache class).

According to the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/) we see that it uses werkzeug:

> Besides providing support for all of werkzeug‘s supported caching backends through a uniformed API

Then when you look at the [werkzeug cache docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/caching/):

> If you are using the development server you can create a SimpleCache object, that one is a simple cache that keeps the item stored in the memory of the Python interpreter.

And then it goes on to show an example using your same setup (`{'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'}`), which it says is in-memory of the Python interpreter.

If you wanna use a different cache backend, look at [Configuring Flask Caching](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/#configuring-flask-caching):

> Built-in cache types:
>
> **null**: NullCache (default)
>
> **simple**: SimpleCache
>
> **memcached**: MemcachedCache (pylibmc or memcache required)
>
> **gaememcached**: GAEMemcachedCache
>
> **redis**: RedisCache (Werkzeug 0.7 required)
>
> **filesystem**: FileSystemCache
>
> **saslmemcached**: SASLMemcachedCache (pylibmc required)

Comment: That's really useful. Thanks